# How to find an average of a list to be with unique identifiers

Tags: python, list, average

So basically I have a list of integers that I would like to get the average of. The thing is I have a second list of strings that is equal length. It's configured in the table below. Now what I essentially need now is to add the sum of integers correlating to the proper letter and return the average of those letters. This is being done on Python 3 and I've been stuck on this issue for the past few days now. Could someone point me in the right direction?

`before`

```
| 2   | a |
+-----+---+
| 241 | b |
+-----+---+
| 21  | a |
+-----+---+
| 512 | b |
+-----+---+
| 142 | a |
+-----+---+
after
+-----+---+
| 165 | a |
+-----+---+
| 753 | b |
+-----+---+
```

Comment: The average of 2, 21, 142 is 165?

Comment: I have sausage fingers

Comment: Are there more than 2 letters?

Comment: Yes there are about 15 unique keys and each with int value and many of the keys are repeating.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

list_1 = [2, 241, 21, 512, 142]
list_2 = ['a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'a']

c = pd.DataFrame()
c['list_1'] = list_1
c['list_2'] = list_2

uniques = c.list_2.unique()
for i in uniques:
    print('sum ' + i + ': ' + str(c[c.list_2==i].list_1.sum()))
    print('mean ' + i + ': ' + str(c[c.list_2==i].list_1.mean()))
```

Comment: I'd rather not use pandas because I am still fairly new to python. I appreciate the effort though

Answer (score 0):

Let's suppose that `list1 = [2, 241, 21, 512, 142]` and `list2 = ['a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'a']` as you described. I don't know what the exact constraints you have, but let me use two dictionaries in addition to the initial setting.

1. Get unique keys in `list2` and count the number of keys.

Let's define an empty dictionary `cnt_dic` for counting the number of keys. After counting keys is done, create a copy of the dictionary `res_dic` with zero-valued.

```py
cnt_dic = {}

for key in list2:
    if key not in cnt_dic: 
        cnt_dic[key] = 1
    else:
        cnt_dic[key] += 1

res_dic = cnt_dic.copy()
for key in res_dic.keys():
    res_dic[key] = 0
```

2. Sum up the integers using collected keys.

```
for num, key in zip(list1, list2):
    res_dic[key] += num
```

3. Calculate averages.

```
for key in cnt_dic.keys():
    res_dic[key] /= cnt_dic[key]
```

Then `res_dic` will contain `{'a': 55.0, 'b': 376.5}`.